# WCF fault handling

Tags: c#, wcf, exception, wcf-faults

**Q** How can I get the original exception (occurred on the server) on the client side?

I am working with a self-hosted WCF service and C# 4 and trying to set up proper exception handling.

I have a client that looks like this

```
private ServiceResponse PerformRemoteAction(ServiceRequest request, ProcessOperations operation)
{
    ...    
    try
    {
        //remote call
        switch (operation)
        {
            ...
            case ProcessOperations.VerifyAction: { response = client.VerifyAction(request); break; } 

            default: throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        AppManager.LogException(ex);
    }

    return response;
}
```

And service implementation

```
public override ServiceResponse VerifyAction(ServiceRequest request)
{
    RegisterRequest(request);

    try
    {
        var chain = new VerificationChain();
        Responce = chain.Run(request);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        throw new FaultException<WcfException>(ExceptionFactory.Create(ex),
            new FaultReason(ex.Message));
    }

    SetSuccessfulResponce();

    return Responce;
}
```

Service web.config has

```
<behaviors>
    <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior>
            <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true" />
        </behavior>
    </serviceBehaviors>
</behaviors>
```

This is my original exception
[image]

And this is what I get on the client[image]

If needed I can post full details on the client side, however the exception on the client does not have any reference to the original one.

**Update**
This is my interface with defined *FaultContractAttribute*

```
[ServiceContract]
public interface IServiceOperation : IOperation
{
    ...
    [OperationContract(Action = "http://tempuri.org/ITestRunnerService/VerifyAction", ReplyAction = "http://tempuri.org/ITestRunnerService/VerifyAction")]
    [FaultContractAttribute(typeof(WcfException), Action = "http://tempuri.org/ITestRunnerService/ExecuteRequestWcfExceptionFault", Name = "WcfException", Namespace = "http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/TH.Core.Exceptions")]
    ServiceResponse VerifyAction(ServiceRequest request);
}
```

And this is my *WcfException* class

```
[DataContract]
public class WcfException : Exception
{
    [DataMember]
    public string Title { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public new string Message { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public new string InnerException { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public new string StackTrace { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for all your answers. My problem was in the service interface, namely in the *Action* property of *FaultContractAttribute*, it pointed to the incorrect URL.

```
[ServiceContract]
public interface IServiceOperation : IOperation
{
    ...
    [OperationContract(Action = "http://tempuri.org/IServiceOperation/VerifyAction", ReplyAction = "http://tempuri.org/IServiceOperation/VerifyAction")]
    [FaultContractAttribute(typeof(WcfException), Action = "http://tempuri.org/IServiceOperation/ExecuteRequestWcfExceptionFault", Name = "WcfException", Namespace = "http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/TH.Core.Exceptions")]
    ServiceResponse VerifyAction(ServiceRequest request);
}
```

I solved it by removing all other properties (to be determined automatically) and left only the type of WcfFault

```
[ServiceContract]
    public interface IServiceOperation : IOperation
    {
        ...
        [OperationContract(Action = "http://tempuri.org/IServiceOperation/VerifyAction", ReplyAction = "http://tempuri.org/IServiceOperation/VerifyAction")]
        [FaultContractAttribute(typeof(WcfException))]
        ServiceResponse VerifyAction(ServiceRequest request);
    }
```

Answer (score 4):

Have you tried to catch a FaultException instead?

```
catch (FaultException<WcfException> ex)
{
   AppManager.LogException(ex);
}
catch (FaultException unknownFault)
{
   AppManager.LogException(unknownFault);
}
```

You will need to include a [FaultContractAttribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.faultcontractattribute.aspx) in your contract for this to work.

Comment: tnx for the reply, it's not working. Anyway, FaultException is Exception and it doesn't change much if I catch a child exception or a parent one. I didn't want to have lengthy block of catches and it is ok for my situation.

Comment: @oleksii: did you also add the FaultContractAttribute on your operation?

Comment: @Christia.K it was there initially, I will try to see the trace info.

Answer (score 3):

What is `WcfException` and is it serializable?

In any case, I suggest you enable tracing on the server as described in [this MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733025.aspx) - this should help you diagnose the problem.

Comment: yeah it is serializable. I will check the trace now.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to have information about original exception it is enough to use:

```
<behaviors>
    <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior>
            <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true" />
        </behavior>
    </serviceBehaviors>
</behaviors>
```